# Error: Can't draw more than one boxplot per group. Did you forget aes(group = ...)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, group

I'm getting an error while trying to plot a boxplot. It says I haven't specified the group variable but as you can see, I have. But I'm not sure why this error keeps popping up. Any ideas?

```
ggplot(fl_n_net, mapping = aes(x = Season, fill = Habitat, group = interaction(Season, Habitat),
                                           lower = mean(Modularity) - sd(Modularity),
                                           upper = mean(Modularity) + sd(Modularity), middle = mean(Modularity),
                                           ymin = mean(Modularity) - 3 * sd(Modularity), ymax = mean(Modularity) + 3 * sd(Modularity))) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.1))

Error: Can't draw more than one boxplot per group. Did you forget aes(group = ...)?
```

This is what my data looks like:
[image: Data]

Comment: Well, did you forget `aes(group=...)`?  We don't know, becaue you haven't shared (part of) your data. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: @Limey Sorry, I have edited it to provide some information.

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to summarize per group inside `aes`, which you cannot do. When you do, for example `middle = mean(Modularity)`, this is not calculated for each of your boxes, but simply the grand mean is applied to *all* your boxes. Instead of trying to do everything inside ggplot, simply group and summarize your data en route to ggplot using `group_by` and `summarize`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

fl_n_net %>%
  group_by(Season, Habitat) %>%
  summarize(ymin   = mean(Modularity) - 3 * sd(Modularity), 
            ymax   = mean(Modularity) + 3 * sd(Modularity), 
            lower  = mean(Modularity) - sd(Modularity), 
            upper  = mean(Modularity) + sd(Modularity),
            middle = mean(Modularity)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Season, fill = Habitat)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = 'identity', 
               aes(fill = Habitat, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
                   lower = lower, middle = middle, upper = upper))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we do not have your data in a format we can use, so I created a sample dataset for the above example. You obviously do not require this part:

```r
set.seed(1)

fl_n_net <- data.frame(
  Season = rep(c('Spring', 'Summer', 'Autmun', 'Winter'), each = 15),
  Habitat = rep(rep(c('Desert', 'Tundra', 'Rainforest'), each = 5), 4))

fl_n_net <- within(fl_n_net, 
       Modularity <- rnorm(60, as.numeric(factor(Season)) * 
                          as.numeric(factor(Habitat))))
```